# jQuery .live('click') fires even on disabled buttons

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I'm using the latest versions (jQuery 1.7.1 and jQuery UI 1.8.16) of all libraries, but buttons that I've binded a .live('click') event to still fire even when the button is disabled. When I bind a regular .click() event to it, it does not fire.

Any suggestions? I'm thinking either I'm using .live() improperly or this is a bug in jQuery UI.

Here's a JSFiddle to demonstrate.
http://jsfiddle.net/Kb66j/1/

Thanks!
Alex

Comment: Your code appears to be working fine in Firefox but creating problems in Chrome and Safari. [This was reported as a bug a while ago](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8165), not sure about its status.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of version 1.7, [.live() has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/).

> "As of jQuery 1.7, the .live() method is deprecated. Use [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) to
>   attach event handlers."

Also, as of version 1.7, [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is preferred over [.bind()](http://api.jquery.com/bind/)

> "As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for
>   attaching event handlers to a document."

Comment: Problem solved! I replaced all .live() listeners with .on() and it works great. Thanks!

Comment: @Sparky672: It does not work for me if I convert the code in the `.on` equivalent: http://jsfiddle.net/Kb66j/6/ Am I doing something wrong? Only because a method is deprecated does not mean that using another way to do the same thing will result in different behaviour.

Comment: @user969352: If you just replaced `on` with `live`, then will not create the same behaviour. It will behave like you replaced `live` with `click`.

Comment: @FelixKling, this answer solved it for the OP.  Perhaps you can post a better solution explaining why simply using `on()` is not good enough and deserves down-votes.

Comment: The correct (or at least a better) answer  and explanation of the problem was provided by @ShankarSangoli. The OP already knows that simply using `click` instead of `live` does solve the problem. You suggest to switch `live` to `on`, which he apparently did in the wrong way (without knowing it) and now he ended up using something equivalent to using `click`. So you could have also just written *"use `click` instead of `live`"*. Changing `live` to an equivalent `on` (what you suggest) **does not solve** the problem at hand. Therefore your answer is not useful imo.

Comment: @FelixKling, My answer was apparently very useful to the OP, but that's beside the point now.  After reading your recent comment, _"I'm not sure anymore wether the reason you [ShankarSangoli] provide is correct."_, I'm left wondering if anyone can post the conclusive answer on this issue.

Comment: It seems to me the answer is that this a bug in Chrome and Safari (Webkit?) and one therefore has to wait until this is fixed or use workarounds such as posted by ShankarSangoli.

Comment: UI puts a span inside the button, and *that* element becomes `event.target` in the event. The browser doesn't deliver the event to the button since it is disabled, but it *does* bubble the event up the tree, including to `document` where the `.live()` event is bound. jQuery has a check in its event handling for the event target  being a disabled button, but since the `event.target` is a span and not a button the check has no effect.

Answer (score 6):

That is because `live` takes advantage of event bubbling. When you `click` on a disabled button the event is still bubbled so the live triggers the event and all the `click` event handlers are executed. You can check the enabled state of the button inside the handler before you execute anything. Try this

```
$("#the_button").button({
        icons: {
            primary: "ui-icon-disk"
        },
    disabled: true
}).live('click',function () {
    if($(this).is(':enabled')){
         alert('clicked');
    }
});
```

Working **[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Kb66j/3/)**

Also as stated by others `live` is deprecated from 1.7+ version so you might try and use `on` but this issue will still be there and you have to handle it the way I described above.

Comment: Actually the problem seems to have disappeared when I switched everything to .on().

Comment: @user969352 - It is working fine because you might have not passed the `selector` to `on` method which is second optional arugment. If `selector` is omitted or is null, the event handler is referred to as direct or directly-bound which was not the case with `live` which purely works on event bubbling mechanism as it attaches the event handler at the `document` level.

Comment: I'm not sure anymore wether the reason you provide is correct. Apparently this problem only exists in Chrome and Safari (don't know about Opera).

Comment: @FelixKling = The reason is provided here http://api.jquery.com/on/. Check under Direct and delegated events section.

Comment: So? Imo the click on a disabled button should not even trigger an event and it seems to work correctly in Firefox. Anyways, [the problem was known](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/live-inconsistency-with-disabled-buttons) (and [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8165)) and it is said it was fixed in 1.5. Now the question is whether this bug is new or it wasn't fixed after all.

Comment: Yes, you are correct and I think it is potentially a new bug.

Answer (score 0):

[live has been deprecated](http://api.jquery.com/live/)

use the new on() method instead

Comment: yes, it does solve the problem.  thanks for the downvote for no apparent reason

Comment: Yeah, the downvote was probably too much. I wouldn't have done it but other people are more rigorous.

Comment: @FelixKling Only shows this behavior on Chrome 16 (webkit?), on ie8 :-) and firefox 9 it doesn't fire, I don't have a safari browser available now...

Comment: yeah, dont be so quick to invalidate correct responses for edge cases

Comment: @rene: Interesting, I haven't considered cross-browser issues. It does fire in Safari too. So it seems to be a bug in jQuery as it does not handle this consistently. Also, the OP's original  code shows the same behaviour.

Comment: @cpjolicoeur: I wouldn't call it an edge case if it does not work properly in Chrome and Safari. And the OPs `live` does not fire in Firefox as well (i.e. it worked), so technically your answer did not change anything.